# Compute the value of the sum $\sum u_n$ where $u_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} \times\left\lfloor\frac{\ln (n)}{\ln (2)}\right\rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Compute the value of the sum $\sum u_n$ where $u_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} \times\left\lfloor\frac{\ln (n)}{\ln (2)}\right\rfloor$.

I already know that this sum converges (see for example [Show that the series $\sum_{n>0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left \lfloor \frac{\ln n}{\ln 2} \right \rfloor$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366076/show-that-the-series-sum-n0-frac-1nn-left-lfloor-frac-ln-n-ln) ).

But I have no idea how to find the value of $\sum u_n$

Comment: Is there a reason to think $\sum u_n$ has a simple closed form? You can get an arbitrarily close numerical approximation though, since the contributing factor is $\frac{\ln n}n$ and the map $n\mapsto\frac{\ln n}n$ is strictly decreasing for $n\ge 2$, so the terms get smaller and smaller pretty quickly in absolute value.

Comment: The only thing I can think of: For $2^k\leq n<2^{k+1},$ $\lfloor \log n/\log 2\rfloor =k.$ $$\sum_{n=2^{k}}^{2^{k+1}-1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left\lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log 2}\right\rfloor =k\sum_{n=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}.$$ But I don’t see how that helps.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor = \gamma$$
the Euler–Mascheroni constant. See [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL13/Pilehrood/pilehrood2.pdf) for a proof. This was proved by G. Vacca in his article "A new series for the Eulerian constant γ = .577 ···", Quart. J. Pure Appl.
Math. 41(1910), 363–364.